# Java display block capitals made up of small letters

Tags: java, string, formatting

I would like to write a method that displays one's initials in block letters, making large letters out of corresponding small letters, eg:

```
MMMMMMMMMM    CCCCCCCCC
MM  MM  MM    CCCCCCCCC
MM  MM  MM    CC
MM  MM  MM    CC
MM  MM  MM    CC
MM      MM    CCCCCCCCC
MM      MM    CCCCCCCCC
```

Any ideas as to how I should go about this?

Comment: Have the letters in file read from User's input their initials and read from appropriate files?

Comment: i am new to java so help me out a bit.. please!! :)

Comment: Look for a program called `figlet` and download their fonts file.  It might give you some ideas.

Comment: @David.. If you continue to get help for your evry problem, you'll always assume yourself new to JAva.. Experience makes a Man OLD.. :)

Comment: Still, have tried anything till yet??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to have a way of creating each individual letter (A, B, ..., Z). Store these as `String[]`s. For example, your M would be:

```
{MMMMMMMMMM, MM  MM  MM, MM  MM  MM, MM  MM  MM, MM  MM  MM, MM      MM, MM      MM}
```

I've just taken all of the lines and stored them as an array. Now if you have 2 `String[]`, say `letter1` and `letter2`, you can 'concatenate' them like this:

```
String[] concat = new String[letter1.length];
for (int i = 0 ; i < concat.length ; i++)
    concat[i] = letter1[i] + "\t" + letter2[i];
```

Now you simply print:

```
for (String s : concat)
    System.out.println(s);
```

---

In your case it would be something like this:

```
// letter1 and letter2 would be created by some other method that you must define
String[] letter1 = new String[]{"MMMMMMMMMM", "MM  MM  MM", "MM  MM  MM", "MM  MM  MM", "MM  MM  MM", "MM      MM", "MM      MM"};
String[] letter2 = new String[]{"CCCCCCCCC" , "CCCCCCCCC", "CC       ", "CC       ", "CC       ", "CCCCCCCCC", "CCCCCCCCC"};

String[] concat = new String[letter1.length];
for (int i = 0 ; i < concat.length ; i++)
    concat[i] = letter1[i] + "\t" + letter2[i];

for (String s : concat)
    System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: A nice improvement upon this might be to replace the M's and C's in your `letter1` and `letter2` arrays with 1's and 0's or booleans.  They would just be shape descriptors then, and you could call a method in your concatenation loop to add the chars back in. This would give you a little flexibility and make your stored strings (read from a file, perhaps?) more uniform.